# How do I seed IdentityUser references in an Entity Framework application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

I have an Entity Framework application using ASP.NET Identity 2.2 (i.e., my context inherits from `IdentityDbContext<T>` and I have a `User` class that inherits from `IdentityUser`). I am successfully seeding the `AspNetUsers` table using the following calls in my seed method:

```
var testUser = new User() {
  UserName = "TestUser",
  Email = "TestUser@Domain.tld"
};

manager.Create(testUser, "TestPassword");
```

I have extended the model to include a `Post` class which includes a reference to my `User` class:

```
public class Post {

  public Post() {}

  [Required]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public User User { get; set; }

}
```

And, of course, this corresponds to the following in my `User` class:

```
public class User : IdentityUser {

  public User() : base() {
    this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
  }

  public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

  //Additional members...
}
```

I am then seeding the `Posts` collection with the following:

```
 var testPost = new Post() { Id = 1, User = testUser };

 context.Posts.AddOrUpdate(
   post => post.Id,
   testPost
 );
```

Technically, this works fine; the `Post` instance is created, and the automatically generated `User_Id` field is correctly populated with the `Id` of the newly created `User` instance.

So what's the problem? Every time it runs, I get the following in my `EntityValidationErrors`: "The User field is required". It doesn't prevent my application from working, but it makes it difficult to detect legitimate errors.

Obviously, I could add custom code to my `DbContext.SaveChanges()` method in order to ignore this error, but I'd rather understand why it's happening in the first place, particularly if there's a problem with how I'm seeding my data.

Comment: Do you still get this error if you first insert the user, call SaveChanges() and then insert the post with another SaveChanges()?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - That doesn't work, but I did find a solution (and am about to post the answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when the `UserManager.Create()` method is called, it doesn't update the `User` instance with the information needed to create a reference. My assumption is that it's not populating the `Id` field, but I haven't confirmed.

Regardless, the solution is to reload the user after the call to `UserManager.Create()`. My final code looks something like:

```
var manager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(context));

var testUser = new User() {
  UserName = "TestUser",
  Email = "TestUser@Domain.tld"
};

if (manager.Users.Count<User>() == 0) {
  manager.Create(testUser, "TestPassword");
}

testUser = (User)manager
  .Users
  .Where<User>(u => u.UserName == "TestUser")
  .FirstOrDefault<User>();
```

I was then able to seed the `Post` record the same way as before:

```
var testPost = new Post() { Id = 1, User = testUser };

context.Posts.AddOrUpdate(
  post => post.Id,
  testPost
);
```

> *Note:* If using a `[ForeignKey]` attribute, it is apparently necessary to assign the `User` by `Id` (e.g., `UserId = testUser.Id`) instead of by object reference (e.g., `User = testUser`).

In my actual application this is all shuffled off to a `CreateUser()` helper method so it's easy to create multiple test users, but this covers the basics. This also addresses a flaw in my original code in that I wasn't previously checking to determine if the user had already been created or not.

Comment: Re the gelato comment, the user's name appears here https://www.gelato.network/about and they have another post on the network (on ethereum.se) promoting the product. By the way, I'd prefer not having such discussions directly on the user's posts. Feel free to ping me in a chatroom I lurk in, or leave a comment under one of my old answers, like I've just done on your answer.